# Rails 3 - ActiveRecord + MySQL and RANDOM function

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, random, model

I need to get from database 3 random items, I have this query:

```
User.joins(:user_cities).where("user_cities.city_id = ?", > @city.id).offset(rand(User.count)).limit(3)
```

and this generate me:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_cities` ON `user_cities`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE (user_cities.city_id = 1) LIMIT 3 OFFSET 15
```

Where the `RAND` function lost? This query returns empty set, when I remote `OFFSET 15`, so I get some 3 results, but every time the same results.

What's wrong with the `RAND` function in ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not have any rand method. You are using a rand method provided by ruby Kernal class.

When you use rand(num) ruby find a random number between 0 and that number.

To retrieve three random records you could do

```
User.joins(:user_cities).where("user_cities.city_id = ?", > @city.id).order('rand()').limit(3)
```